# Artifactory ignores artifacts deployed into libs-release-local

Tags: maven-2, artifactory

We are evaluating Artifactory to be used as our local/remote repository. Our application uses a custom **cxf-2.6.6 jar.**  We've manually deployed the cxf jar into **libs-release-local**. But each time we do a local build, Artifactory downloads  a version of cxf 2.6.6 from the remote maven repository into **ext-release-local**. As a result there will be two copies of cxf 2.6.6.jar and unfortunately our local build uses only the downloaded cxf instead of the one we deployed.

Both **libs-release-local** & **ext-release-local** are mapped to the same virtual repository **libs-release**, so this is strange. Even if I delete the cxf from ext-release-local it downloads again. How do I restrict this? I could probably deploy the cxf into ext-release-local (I haven't tried)?

But then isn't it a bug? Please advice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can control the resolution order of a virtual repository: Admin -> Repositories -> Edit (Virtual repository) -> Drag & drop repository names in the "Selected Repositories" box.
The "Resolved Repositories" box will reflect the order in which the resolution is performed.
Generaly speaking the search/resolution order when requesting artifacts from a virtual repository is always: local repositories, remote repository caches and finally remote repositories themselves.

If you are using Artifactory 2.6.0 or newer, you can use the [Trace Artifact Retrieval](http://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/RTF/Artifactory+REST+API#ArtifactoryRESTAPI-TraceArtifactRetrieval) feature to emulate an artifact retrieval request from the specified location and returns verbose output about the resolution process.